# Кликабильные слова, chat id пользователей

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Пишу телеграмм бота на питоне через пичарм.Подскажите, как сделать кликабильные слова с переходом на сайт (например, с кликом на слово "сайт" осуществляется переход по ссылке)? Также интересует вопрос: как собирать логи подписчиков для дальнейшей отправки рассылки?

Comment: Вопрос по ссылкам решён ! [сайт](сайт.рф)

Comment: что значит *собирать логи подписчиков*?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы отправить в чат ссылку со своей надписью, включите форматирование Markdown, а в тексте сообщения используйте типичное форматирование.

```
[тескт ссылки будет отображён пользователю](https://core.telegram.org/bots)
```

Возможно альтернативное HTML-форматирование.

```
<a href="https://core.telegram.org/bots">тескт ссылки будет отображён пользователю</a>
```

Чтобы эта функциональность заработала, надо соответствующим образом указать параметр **parse_mode** метода [sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage).

Учтите, что прежде чем перейти по указанному адресу, пользователь получит диалоговое окно с полным адресом, куда он будет перенаправлен. Не пытайтесь жульничать.